# css: how to override max-width value with a larger (less restrictive) value

Tags: overriding, css

I have a css file with this style:

```
.filefield-element .widget-edit {max-width: 70%;}
```

I wanted to increase the max-width without modifying that css file, so I created a custom css file with this style:

```
.filefield-element .widget-edit {max-width: 99%;}
```

In the "html/styles" pane, I see that the styles are listed in the correct order:

```
.filefield-element .widget-edit {
    max-width: 99%;
}

.filefield-element .widget-edit {
    float: left;
    max-width: 70%;
}
```

However, "max-width: 99%" is not overriding "max-width: 70%".  It seems that the more restrictive value (70%) is used, even when the less-restrictive value (99%) comes first.

Is there a way to override a max-width value with a larger (less restrictive) value?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can override (unset) max-width with

```
.foo{ max-width:none; }
```

... to clear any inherited max-width.

Comment: ``width: auto`` but ``max-width: none`` wtf were w3c thinking or whoever decided this

Comment: @OZZIE, the names make perfect sense.  `max-width` is "nullable": you either have one or you don't.  Whereas an element always has a `width`, which may or may not be explicit.  `auto` allows you to explicitly revert to the implicit width, but the width still exists.

Comment: Ahhh...been bonkers for few minutes.

Answer (score 10):

Try using `!important`, or *selector* with **higher** specificity.

Example:

```
  max-width: none !important;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried both methods -- adding !important and creating a selector with higher specificity -- but still no luck.  Here is the style I tried:   div.form-item .filefield-element .widget-edit {
  max-width: 99% !important;

}

Comment: To clarify, I think the problem may be specific to "max-width".  The more restrictive max-width is (apparently) used, even if a less-restrictive max-width has precedence.

Comment: There's nothing magic about max-width. As you can see in this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/hNu8v/) the last declaration is the one that takes. (Edit: or the one with highest specificity).

Answer (score 3):

This is a specificity issue. Take a look at http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/.

Basically, you need to make one more specific than the other. Put the containing element before `.filefield-element .widget-edit` and it will be overridden

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Still no luck.  I tried changing ".filefield-element .widget-edit" to ".form-item .filefield-element .widget-edit".

Comment: I know this is old, but thought I'd add the following. If you look he says he was looking at it in the "html/styles" pane. In the style pane in most inspectors it shows the most overriding and highest specificity rules first. So there was no problem with specificity.

Answer (score 3):

Use *JavaScript* to set `max-width` to `none` first, then reassign a new value.